# Common Access Card Instead of UN and PW

Tags: security, restricted-access

Is there a feature in Ubuntu that can allow users to gain access via a common access card instead of a username and password?

Or maybe only allowing access to sensitive files by use of a valid access card.

Yes, I know you need a card reader and access cards. My question is, where can I locate this feature if it exists?